# Install R in Linux Server

Tags: r, linux

I have tried install R in Linux operated server system. I have download latest version of R from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/R-3.4.1.tar.gz)

Then I started to install

`./configure --prefix=$HOME/R-3.4.1 --enable-R-shlib

And I get configure error: "zlib library and headers are required".

I install and configure zlib.1.2.11 and try again but still get same error.

I couldn't solve this problem.

Comment: Is there some reason for compiling from source, as opposed to using the package manager of your distribution?

Comment: Yes, I have to work in a server and send job there. Because my R codes running for days

Comment: Try again with `./configure --prefix=$HOME/R --enable-R-shlib`. If that fails take note of any errors in the configure log, add them to your question.

Comment: cross-posted: https://askubuntu.com/questions/958041/install-r-in-linux-server

Answer (score 4):

**Note - Considering your situation and provided details, I see these possible solutions :**

## 1 - Ubtunu(Debian-based) system, Installing from package manager :

This require the user to have installation rights on your machine.

Open a terminal, and type this command.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install r-base
```

This will update your packages info and install R main package (r-base).
As pointed out by @Touqeer you can install only the dependencies with this command.

```
sudo apt build-dep r-base
```

## 2 - Ubuntu(Debian-based) system, Installing from source :

If you don't have installation rights on your machine, you can proceed with source code. Thanks to the folks at [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958041/install-r-in-linux-server) for this part. Dont forget to change the package version on the following code if necessary.

```
wget http://cran.rstudio.com/src/base/R-3/R-3.4.1.tar.gz
tar xvf R-3.4.1.tar.gz
cd R-3.4.1
./configure --prefix=$HOME/R
make && make install
```

This will download the required files from CRAN directly. Next it will unzip the files into a directory. After this `cd` command will bring you into the created directory. Finally, you will install R with the `./configure` and the `make && make install` commands.

Always check that you are in the good working directory. If the `./configure` or `make && make install` commands fails, you may have dependencies problems. Basicaly, you will have to do approximatively the same procedure with the missing package and so on with his dependencies. @knb at AskUbuntu propose to change the configuration file to something like `configure -- with-zlib=$HOME/zlib-1.2.11` ,using the zlib dependency as example, to force a dependency path into the config file.

Keep us posted!